# How to import related products through programmatically in magento2?

Tags: admin, magento2.2.4

I don't know how to import related products programmatically. Can you please help me with this task?

Comment: Did you tried this - https://community.magento.com/t5/Can-Magento-do/Can-Magento-bulk-import-related-products/m-p/48333

Comment: Do you want to get all product's related products ?

Comment: Hi @ Rohan Hapani, I want to import related products for each product as a through CSV from magento2 import option

Comment: Hi @ LAW, I want to import related products for each product as a through CSV from magento2 import option

Comment: Hi @ Rohan Hapani,  Can you please help me this task?

Comment: Related products of what ?

Comment: Hi @ avesh,  I want to import related products for each product as a through CSV from magento2 import option